# How to change the FIELD TERMINATED value for an existing Hive table?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I currently have a table `t1` which was set a value of `'\t'` in my `FIELD TERMINATED` clause.

Now I would like to change that particular clause in structure of the *Table* `t1`.

Is there any way to `ALTER` the `FIELD TERMINATED` clause after creation?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
hive >

ALTER TABLE table_name    
set serde 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim' = '|');
```

---

It works. Check `DESC FORMATTED tbl_name` before and after applying the query. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks a lot. This answer is very useful.

Comment: When I changed the delimiter only - which is to say SerDe properties only, not changing which SerDe - `ALTER TABLE table_name SET SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim' = ',');` sufficed - https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-AddSerDeProperties

Answer (score 1):

As already stated by Randall , it did not work directly.
So solution is below which seems catching .

```
ALTER TABLE table_name SET SERDEPROPERTIES ('field.delim' = ',');
```